# Как реализовать шифрование данных на PHP

Tags: php, javascript, aes, cryptojs

Вот пример на JS:

```
function decryptRandomNumber (pwdHash, encryptedRandomNumber) {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwdHash);

    var encrypted = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedRandomNumber.toUpperCase());

    var result = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: encrypted
    }, key , {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    return result;
}

function encryptPwdHash (pwdHash, randomNumber) {

    var randomNumberMd5 = CryptoJS.MD5(randomNumber).toString().toUpperCase();
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(randomNumberMd5);
    var result = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(pwdHash), key, {
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    }).ciphertext;

    return result;
}
// пример на js - шифрование
 var password = '123456';
 var pwdHash = CryptoJS.MD5(password).toString().toUpperCase();
 var encriptResult = encryptPwdHash (pwdHash, '3456'); //
```

Скриншот результата
[image: gdfgdfgdfg]
     если привести в строку то *f46492dc512a6df5cd7c6b9ee50e7cc44fb2337c1605726518d353ce800d5cc05d4d5540dd7674850079e785ab5f3b77*

Нужно переписать на PHP.

Расшифровку смог сделать вот этой функцией

```
 function aes128_cbc_decrypt($key, $data, $iv) {
     $data = pack("H*", $data);
     $iv = pack("H*", $iv);
     $dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,   $iv);
     return $dec;
 }
```

Входящие параметры --> `$key = strtoupper(md5($password));`
 хеш пароля 
`$data = '54BAA6158E81E1069EA2AB1C4F9D1F29';`- хеш рандомного числа `$iv = '00000000000000000000000000000000';` - вектор в виде 16 - ти ричной константы.

Вот теперь нужно зашифровать обратно пароль с помощью случайного числа и отправить. Написал функцию которая делает подобное:

```
function aes128_cbc_encript($key, $data, $iv) {
    $key = pack("H*", strtoupper(md5($key)));
    //var_dump($data);
    //$data = pack("H*", $data);
    $iv = pack("H*", $iv);
    //$enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    $enc = openssl_encrypt($data,  'AES-128-CBC', $key, true, $iv);
    return bin2hex($enc);
 }
```

Пробую запускать

```
$decript = '34345'; // расшифрованное рандомное число
$pswdHash = strtoupper(md5($password));

$encript = aes128_cbc_encript($decript, $pswdHash, '00000000000000000000000000000000');
```

На выходе получаю нечто - `72fc1b49db86787b749c3323421496af00933eb79a9b7d845a51f5ea3fefdf750800554f5fdf0c7d3d765fe7f6653da3`

Такой шифр и должен быть по длинне и в 16 - ти разрядном виде, но он не правильный и при отправке на сервер он не расшифровуется.

Вот пример функции на Oracle, которая на сервере делает расшифровку

```
    Fc_Decrypt_Password_Hash(In_Encrypted_Password_Hash In Varchar2,
          In_Random_Number_Md5  In Varchar2) Return Varchar2 Is
          Raw_Random_Number_Md5 Raw(2000);
          Raw_Result            Raw(2000);
          Result                Varchar2(2000);
  Begin
      Raw_Random_Number_Md5 := Utl_I18n.String_To_Raw(Upper(In_Random_Number_Md5), 'AL32UTF8');
      Raw_Result := Dbms_Crypto.Decrypt(Typ => Dbms_Crypto.Aes_Cbc_Pkcs5, Src => Upper(In_Encrypted_Password_Hash), Key => Raw_Random_Number_Md5);
     Result := Utl_I18n.Raw_To_Char(Raw_Result, 'AL32UTF8');
   Return(Result);
  End;
```

Comment: Зачем вы вообще это все шифруете? Не проще ли установить безопасный канал до сервера, если там все равно все расшифровывается?

Comment: @Etki Ну вот такая задача стоит, для обмена данными с сервером используются зашифрованные ключи

Comment: https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, если вы действительно хотите защитить обмен сообщениями - пользуйтесь готовыми решениями.

Функция `openssl_encrypt` не использует весь `$key`, а только первые 16 байт, остальные отбрасываются (для AES-128). Хотя это только практический опыт, возможно это верно не для всех версий. В качестве `$key` у вас используется хэш `md5` в 16-ричном формате, а это 32 байта. 
`CryptoJS`, использует весь ключ (или по крайней мере больше 16 байт).

Ожидать, что результаты шифрований совпадут, не приходится.

Функция `mcrypt_encrypt` не умеет `Pkcs7`. Она всегда выравнивает блок нулями (и это небезопасно). Хоть в вашем случае выравнивание и не требуется (длина исходного текста всегда делится на 16), по вышеуказанному стандарту все равно нужно добавить выравнивание, это будут 16 байт `0x10`.

Пример рабочего кода (практически повторяет ваш пример на js):

```
function encrypt(){
  $data=strtoupper(md5('123456'));
  $data.=str_repeat(chr(16), 16);// добавляем выравнивание
  $key=strtoupper(md5('3456'));
  $iv=hex2bin(str_repeat('00', 16));
  $enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
  return bin2hex($enc);
}
var_dump(encrypt()); // -> string(96) "f46492dc512a6df5cd7c6b9ee50e7cc44fb2337c1605726518d353ce800d5cc05d4d5540dd7674850079e785ab5f3b77"
```

Answer (score 3):

Так как у вас стоит задача просто реализовать зашифрованный обмен данными между клиентом и сервером, предлагаю просто готовую реализацию.

**PHP библиотека:**

```
/**
* Decrypt data from a CryptoJS json encoding string
*
* @param mixed $passphrase
* @param mixed $jsonString
* @return mixed
*/
function cryptoJsAesDecrypt($passphrase, $jsonString){
    $jsondata = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $salt = hex2bin($jsondata["s"]);
    $ct = base64_decode($jsondata["ct"]);
    $iv  = hex2bin($jsondata["iv"]);
    $concatedPassphrase = $passphrase.$salt;
    $md5 = array();
    $md5[0] = md5($concatedPassphrase, true);
    $result = $md5[0];
    for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $md5[$i] = md5($md5[$i - 1].$concatedPassphrase, true);
        $result .= $md5[$i];
    }
    $key = substr($result, 0, 32);
    $data = openssl_decrypt($ct, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
    return json_decode($data, true);
}

/**
* Encrypt value to a cryptojs compatiable json encoding string
*
* @param mixed $passphrase
* @param mixed $value
* @return string
*/
function cryptoJsAesEncrypt($passphrase, $value){
    $salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8);
    $salted = '';
    $dx = '';
    while (strlen($salted) < 48) {
        $dx = md5($dx.$passphrase.$salt, true);
        $salted .= $dx;
    }
    $key = substr($salted, 0, 32);
    $iv  = substr($salted, 32,16);
    $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt(json_encode($value), 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
    $data = array("ct" => base64_encode($encrypted_data), "iv" => bin2hex($iv), "s" => bin2hex($salt));
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

**Javascript библиотека:**

```
var CryptoJSAesJson = {
    stringify: function (cipherParams) {
        var j = {ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)};
        if (cipherParams.iv) j.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();
        if (cipherParams.salt) j.s = cipherParams.salt.toString();
        return JSON.stringify(j);
    },
    parse: function (jsonStr) {
        var j = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
        var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(j.ct)});
        if (j.iv) cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(j.iv)
        if (j.s) cipherParams.salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(j.s)
        return cipherParams;
    }
}
```

**Пример на Javascript:**

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify("value to encrypt"), "my passphrase", {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
var decrypted = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "my passphrase", {format: CryptoJSAesJson}).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

**Пример на PHP**

```
$encrypted = cryptoJsAesEncrypt("my passphrase", "value to encrypt");
$decrypted = cryptoJsAesDecrypt("my passphrase", $encrypted);
```

Взято [остюда](https://github.com/brainfoolong/cryptojs-aes-php)

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант не работает для моего сервера, я должен подстраиваться под js скрипт, который работает а на php не работает зашифровка данных, он не может расшифровать то что я ему отправляю

Comment: @modelfak а что мешает вам переписать скрипт?

Comment: @modelfak вы понимаете, что существуют вполне конкретные алгоритмы шифрования, записанные далеко не в вашем скрипте?

Comment: @Etki да я понимаю, это aes-128, я не могу зашифровать данные по аналогии с cryptoJs и не понимаю почему

Comment: @modelfak в моем варианте aes-256. В чем проблема использовать этот рабочий пример. Если вам нужно именно aes-128, то достаточно будет внести несколько правок.

Answer (score -1):

Переписал все полностью, если это оно, то прокомментирую после вашего подтверждения.

```
<?

# ваша функция дешифрования
function aes128_cbc_decrypt($key, $data, $iv) {
  $data = pack("H*", $data);
  $iv = pack("H*", $iv);
  $dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,   $iv);
  return $dec;
}
# расшифровываю ваши данные вашей функцией
echo aes128_cbc_decrypt(strtoupper(md5('123456')), '54BAA6158E81E1069EA2AB1C4F9D1F29', '00000000000000000000000000000000') . '<br><br>';
# вы зашифровали: 1152


# моя функция для шифрования в режиме CBC
function dataEncrypt($plaintext, $key, $iv)
{
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, pack('H*', $iv));
    $ciphertext = strtoupper(bin2hex($ciphertext));

    return $ciphertext;
}
# шифрую то, что вы шифровали ранне (число 1152) своей функцией
echo dataEncrypt('1152', strtoupper(md5('123456')), '00000000000000000000000000000000') . '<br><br>';
# результат: C3364787440D1A610FB3B99C8C6D483C


# расшифровываю результат работы своей функции: C3364787440D1A610FB3B99C8C6D483C с помощью вашей функцией aes128_cbc_decrypt
echo aes128_cbc_decrypt(strtoupper(md5('123456')), 'C3364787440D1A610FB3B99C8C6D483C', '00000000000000000000000000000000') . '<br><br>';
# я зашифровал: 1152
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не подходит, со скрипта хавает без проблем, с пхп никак не хочет ((

Comment: @modelfak, приведите пример данных которые вы передаете JS-функции `encryptPwdHash` и результат шифротекста.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос результат  и входящие еданные